# Head loss curves for PEX tubing?

Tags: pressure, hydraulics

Is there a reliable online reference for head losses of PEX tubing at various nominal sizes and flow rates?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.pmengineer.com/articles/86617-minitube-distribution-systems-for-hydronic-radiant-floor-heating) ("Minitube Distribution Systems for Hydronic Radiant Floor Heating", by John Siegehthaler) has a somewhat small / low-quality chart which doesn't seem to cite a refererence / source:

[image]

Maybe this is useful at least to get you "in the ballpark".

---

Uponor ["Pressure Loss Tables"](https://www.uponorpro.com/~/media/Extranet/Files/manuals/PressureLossTables_H191_1210.aspx?sc_lang=en) could be useful; example:
[image]

Although not a graph I believe you could generate a curve from this data; and it it is usefully broken down by tube size, fluid type, and temperature.